# Using `M` instead of `k` when rep is >= 1M on https://chat.stackexchange.com/users

Tags: feature-request, reputation, chat, user-interface

I read on https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=reputation&page=1 ([mirror](https://archive.is/cRohf))

[image]

Shouldn't it be `1.03m` or (if we really follow the conventions of the metric system) `1.03M` instead?

Comment: I shouldn't even be surprised John Skeet gained enough reputation to indirectly cause a bug report.

Comment: Ah, that's combined network rep. For a moment I thought I missed him passing 1M on SO.

Comment: To be consistent with the K, the M shouldn't appear until 10M.

Comment: @zondo http://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=reputation&page=1392 shows 2.4k

Comment: Also affects a lot of other sites now, like "accounts" list, profile overview, all answers he has ever given, etc: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305775/m-in-reputation