# "M" in reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation

Apparently Jon Skeet has decided to test if reputation is stored as an `int` by causing an overflow. On the way there he has broken yet another boundary. He now has more than a million reputation on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

But that causes this weird "1108k" to appear instead of a clean "1.1M":

> [image: Jon Skeet user card]

My feature request is to add the M. And if you're at it, maybe also B, T and Q? That should then be enough until the sun becomes a red giant and engulfs the Stack Exchange servers.

I'm reporting this as a feature request, because so far I wasn't able to see a bug. Since the number of bronze badges already wraps to the next line, he should need a lot more reputation to actually break something.

Comment: Hm, apparently the "jon-skeet" tag doesn't exist anymore. But there are [369 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Jon+Skeet+is%3Aquestion) that include his name!

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295892/using-m-instead-of-k-when-rep-is-1m-on-http-chat-stackexchange-com-user

Comment: Oh, I thought that one was fixed already. Should the other question be edited to also include this one and then this question be closed as a duplicate of that one?

Comment: Regarding the tag: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304040/why-isnt-there-a-jon-skeet-tag.

Comment: No no, the other one is for chat only, and more "urgent" since it actually breaking something.

Comment: Then what is the reason for the downvotes? I think I counted at least three now. Edit: Yep, three.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard What does it break? The bronze badges aren't visible anymore, but that's also the case for a lot of other people.

Comment: And why the title change? It's not milli, but mega: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_prefix#Metric_prefixes

Comment: To be consistent with the "k" and not "K"... feel free to revert the change, nothing critical.

Comment: Downvotes are just because people are against the idea.

Comment: If people reached becomes "m" why not reputation? I agree that 1000k looks a bit odd.  For now, only Jon Skeet is affected, though, so maybe this is not a crisis yet.

Comment: I think we should just have the reputation points stored in standard form.

Comment: A standard form would be 1,000k and only switching to M on 10M.

Comment: Really? Where is such a standard defined? Also I clearly see "2K" in a lot of places.

Comment: That was already the second comment, but it was seen as only related, not a duplicate, because apparently that one actually causes a bug. But I still don't know which one, nobody answered my question regarding that.

Comment: When a user has between 1000 and 10 000 reputation, the complete reputation number is shown and not "k", so it's the same thing when a user has between 1 million and 10 million reputation. When he reaches 10 million reputation, it will probably show as "10M" just like it currently shows "10k" for users with 10 000 reputation.

Comment: Is there a way to confirm that it behaves that way?

Comment: @Fabian I can think of two ways to confirm it. The first one (and the most realistic one) is to ask a Stack Exchange employee who has access to the source code. The second one is to wait until Jon Skeet (or someone else) reaches 10 million reputation, but with the current trajectory that will take about 90 years.

Comment: Then how do you ping a dev efficiently (and the correct one)? I don't want to wait 90 years to click on either "that solved my problem" or "my question is different". Answering this would help answering that.

Comment: @Fabian You could try using the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page, but I'm not sure if that's appropriate since it's not an appropriate issue. You could also try using [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not quite sure how it works since I don't use it so often. In any case, if you get an answer, it would be nice if you post it as a self-answer to this question.

Comment: Also, about the [jon-skeet] tag, I don't think we need one at all. Jon Skeet is just a normal user, he just happens to have a lot of reputation (which is what made him famous). And for this question, it would definitely not be appropriate since it's not specifically about Jon Skeet since other users can also reach 1 million in the future. If you want to know why not, you can read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304040/349538).

Comment: That was already the fourth comment.

Comment: It shows 1.0 m in the user accounts. See in the left side of his account activity page. https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

Comment: Related: [Use abbreviations for 1000+ score in linked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239654/168244)

Comment: @Fabian it's an SE de-facto standard. SE writes out reputation until you reach 10k.

Comment: Ironically, this question gave me the ability that I *could* create the `jon-skeet` tag, if I wanted to.

Comment: Archive for my link from comment#8: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Unit_prefix&oldid=834474375#Metric_prefixes

Comment: Reopened. The other one is for chat, which has a different code base, and much less likely to get any updates.

Answer (score 27):

Jon Skeet strikes again! Jon and other members of the "two comma club" had reputation that  was showing up as `1.2m` in some places and `1235k` in others. This issue is now fixed across all sites and should use the `1.2m` format anywhere that the reputation is shown like this:

[image: A screenshot of Jon Skeet's reputation summary where it now shows 1.2m instead of 1235k]

I'll see you again at 1 billion!

Comment: If anyone reaches that mark I will eat my Winter Bash hats.

Comment: Yay, this calls for celebratory fries from the big yellow M!

Comment: Are those Megareps or Mebireps?

Comment: Those are millireps, it's a lowercase "m".

Comment: @Wrigglenite nice, so I have a million times more reputation than JonSkeet. :)

Comment: @Ollie If anyone reaches that mark I will eat my Winter Bash hats and vomit them.