# Show "M" for million-rep users on chat.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, reputation, chat

Over at the [users listed by reputation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=reputation) page on Chat SE, the users in the "2 comma club" still have their reputation shown in four-digit kays, instead of a nice round M, contrary to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359997/798831) answer:

[image]

(Gilles is ahead of Skeet!!)  As there are currently 6 users up there and another two hard on their well-heeled rep marks, should we apply the `1M` format to the chat lists as well?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Good catch, I didn't see that.  Thanks.